# How to use PowerMock to mock a singleton private method

Tags: java, mockito, powermock

I have a Sigleton class but how to use PoserMock to mock a private method in java?

Is there any sample?

```
public final class ApimSDKImpl implements ApimSDK {
    /**
     * init sdk
     */
    private ApimSDKImpl() {}

    /**
     * set Singelton
     */
    public static ApimSDKImpl getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized (ApimSDKImpl.class) {
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = new ApimSDKImpl();
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }

    /**
     * setSystemConfig
     */
    private String setSystemConfig() {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

how can I use PowerMock to Mock setSystemConfig function?
thanks

Comment: Check this out [Mocking of Private Methods Using PowerMock](https://www.baeldung.com/powermock-private-method)

Comment: And you can find a good example [here](https://automationrhapsody.com/mock-private-method-call-powermock/).